# Animation "stops" when hovering

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using Masonry with filtering ([link masonry](http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/filtering.html)) on my site. I'm trying to implement a "fade" function on the objects in the list.

The problem is that when I filter, and quickly move over the mouse when the animation is running, all the divs get stuck.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 

  //area 1 
  $('.wrap').children().not('.col2').hover(function() { 

    $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(500,0.5); 

  }, function() { 

    $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(500,1); 

  }); 
 }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's actually what your issue is, but `.stop()` without parameters won't clear the animation queue or jump to the end of it, so it will just stop in the middle of a fade (is this what you're referring to?).

Try calling `.stop(true, true)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it! Altough it makes the transitions stuttering when moving the mouse over several objects fast, not at all as smooth as without "true,true" on stop.

Comment: It's true, but a rare case.  Please mark my answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark next to it.